# How to upgrade to GCM 3

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In the past, there were some reliability issues with push notifications with GCM https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/02/12/keeping-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-working-reliably-techincal-post/

In the above link, it is said that those issues were happening in GCM 2 but solved in GCM 3. But how do we update to GCM 3?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to link to the most up to date class library for GCM and you should be all set to go. If you have a standard setup you need to update your build.gradle file, [as described in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).